# response from website is not coming properly

Tags: php, objective-c, authentication, ios6

I am newbie for iPhone application. I have followed [**this tutorial**](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-receive-data-from-the-server-in-iphone/) for login from iPhone.

I have php file as below.

---

## CODE

---

### index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $user = $_POST['uname'];

        if ($user == 'user') {
            echo "Welcome to my site...";
        } else {
            echo "Invalid User";
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run application and enter username as **user** and password as some text, I get output in iPhone as below

---

### OUTPUT

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
            Welcome to my site...
    </body>
</html>
```

The output that I was expecting is only text **Welcome to my site...**, however I get full HTML code.

Any idea why I get like this? What changes do I have to need to do in PHP file?

Comment: What's the name of the file? The content-type?

Nevermind, forget what I said
I don't know much about iPhones, but maybe your server is serving it as something other than text/html?

Comment: Looks like he's calling the whole page, to get only the php part the php file must contain only that

Comment: Yes but he's expecting the HTML to render, which it is not. It's either the iPhone or the OP's server is sending a weird content-type. Seems more likely to be the former.

Comment: This seems like a problem with the server configuration. It's running the PHP script properly, but setting the default `Content-Type:` to `text/plain` instead of `text/html` for the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per the iphone application development tutorial they are using standard sdk for creating buttons and text boxes it is not html, if you want to create your login form using html in iphone use webView, as you are printing full html code it is showing your that only, put only following code in your index.php file

```
<?php
  $user = $_POST['uname'];
  if ($user == 'user') {
       echo "Welcome to my site...";
  } else {
      echo "Invalid User";
  }
?>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is answer... Its working... That means I have to only write what I want in PHP... thats it...

Comment: if you have good tutorial for login for iPhone, can you share me?

Comment: you are doing it right, you just have to use php properly and send json or appropriate output from server and read it in iphone code

Comment: no I am saying you can return json data from php with multiple values for that user and can use in your application

Comment: ok. Now instead of showing message welcome to My Site, what should I do so that I can go to welcome screen?

Answer (score 0):

Your php server prints out anything AS IS, as long as it is not in a php block

```
<?php
  //this is interpreted php code 
?>
```

So it prints out everything html in the file until it reaches a php block of code. It interprets what is in the php block and inserts what you echo at that position of the file. When the php block ends it just spits out everything that follows again - as html in your case.

If you want just the simple text output, you have to leave out the HTML (which is not necessary to make the php work).

If on the other hand, you need the HTML for having access to the site via a web browser too, you better put your evaluation php in a separate php file and point your iPhone app to just this php file. In your HTML file you include this ile via the php require function.

Answer (score 0):

Your php script will output all the Text what you write in the File.

Bevore and after the PHP tag you wrote a HTML Header, Body. Try to remove this:

```
    <?php
    $user = $_POST['uname'];

    if ($user == 'user') {
        echo "Welcome to my site...";
    } else {
        echo "Invalid User";
    }
    ?>
```

But if you try to login a User and then Interact later with the Server, without passing always the User, then Send to the Server the Username, like you did, create a Session, save the User and pass a unique Session ID back to the iPhone.
Then when you connect the next time to the API, you know already the user, and you don't have to revalidate if he is logged in.

Comment: Yes, what you said is valid. as I am newbie, I have to grow up step by step. If you have any good tutorial link can you share me?